# Access value outside of a struct in Swift 3

Tags: swift, struct, swift-structs

I'm trying to implement the `PagingMenuController` for my iOS app Swift 3. See the [full code example here on github](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController/blob/master/Example/PagingMenuControllerDemo2/RootViewControoler.swift).  In this example, they create the viewControllers inside the struct `PagingMenuOptions` (`let viewController1 = ViewController1() ...`). But instead of creating here, I would like to be able to access an array of ViewControllers declared **outside** of the struct `PagingMenuOptions`. But I get an error

> Struct declaration cannot close over value 'self' defined in outer scope.

Any idea how to implement this?

```
private struct PagingMenuOptions: PagingMenuControllerCustomizable {
    fileprivate var componentType: ComponentType {
        return .all(menuOptions: MenuOptions(), pagingControllers: pagingControllers)
    }

    fileprivate var pagingControllers: [UIViewController] {
        let viewController1 = ViewController1()
        let viewController2 = ViewController2()
        return [viewController1, viewController2]
    }

    fileprivate struct MenuOptions: MenuViewCustomizable {
        var displayMode: MenuDisplayMode {
            return .segmentedControl
        }
        var itemsOptions: [MenuItemViewCustomizable] {
            return [MenuItem1(), MenuItem2()]
        }
    }

    fileprivate struct MenuItem1: MenuItemViewCustomizable {
        var displayMode: MenuItemDisplayMode {
            return .text(title: MenuItemText(text: "First Menu"))
        }
    }
    fileprivate struct MenuItem2: MenuItemViewCustomizable {
        var displayMode: MenuItemDisplayMode {
            return .text(title: MenuItemText(text: "Second Menu"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: When I move these two viewController declaration outside of the struct
    "let viewController1 = ViewController1()
    let viewController2 = ViewController2()"
the error append on return [viewController1, viewController2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding a init(xxx) function to the struct PagingMenuOptions and passing the viewControllers array to that function.